# VS 2017 Debug Error

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

I'm getting an error when I try to inspect variables in my VS 2017 C# code.  The errors started with an upgrade.

```
Native View To inspect the native object, enable native code debugging.
```

The a google search suggests the following fix, but I cannot find this option on y Project-Properties-Debug page.

```
To enable debugging of unmanaged code
```

With a project selected in Solution Explorer, on the Project menu, click Properties.
Click the Debug tab.
Select the Enable unmanaged code debugging check box.

Comment: Which kind of C# project did you create? Maybe you could share a screen shot about your project property. For general projects like a WPF/Console app, we could find the Enable native code debugging option under project properties->Debug. Maybe it was related to the real project type you create like Keys' suggestion like .NET core app or others.

Comment: What about this issue? Would you please share the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try This

add the following to your profile in launchsettings.json

"nativeDebugging" : true

I have also read some posts it says like 
starting in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 you should be able to set `<EnableUnmanagedDebugging>true</EnableUnmanagedDebugging>` in your .csproj file.